# Setting/ Changing Response header always

Tags: c#, http-headers

We are struggling with an issue.

We want to achieve the following, in all scenarios:

1. If the header is present, overwrite it and set it to the value
   received as the parameter.
2. If the header is not present, add the header with the value received as the parameter.

We have tried **AddHeader()** or **AppendHeader()** but it will just Append the value. Since it would be a generic scenario, I am expecting that there would be an in-built method for it. So I am not going for a snippet.

Please help with the method name.

Comment: Received Headers (in a response) are readonly!  Here is an example of server response code h ttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse?force_isolation=true&view=netframework-4.8:

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `response.Headers.Remove("Your-Header")` before `Add("Your-Header", "value")`.